# D3 V4 Tree Search and Highlight

Tags: javascript, loops, d3.js, tree

So, I really love this example from Jake Zieve shown here: https://bl.ocks.org/jjzieve/a743242f46321491a950

Basically, on search for a term, the path to that node is highlighted. I would like to accomplish something similar but with the following caveats:

1. I would like to stay in D3 v4.
2. I'm concerned about cases where the path doesn't clear out on next node pick OR **what happens when there are two nodes of the same
   name** (I would ideally like to highlight all paths)
3. I would like to AVOID using JQuery

Given a set search term (assume you're already getting the string from somewhere) I know I need to make use of the following lines specifically (you can see my stream of consciousness in the comments) but I'm just not quite sure where to start.

```
// Returns array of link objects between nodes.
var links1 = root.descendants().slice(1); //slice to get rid of company.
console.log(links1); //okay, this one is nice because it gives a depth number, this describes the actual link info, including the value, which I am setting link width on. 
var links2 = root.links(); // to get objects with source and target properties. From here, I can pull in the parent name from a selected target, then iterate again back up until I get to source. Problem: what if I have TWO of the same named nodes??? 
console.log(links2);
```

Thoughts on this? I'll keep trying on my own, but I keep hitting roadblocks. My code can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/KateJean/7o3suadx/

[UPDATE]
I was able to add a filter to the links2 to call back a specific entry. See
For example:

```
var searchTerm = "UX Designer"
var match = links2.filter(el => el.target.data.name === searchTerm); //full entry
console.log(match);
```

This single entry gives me all associated info, including the full list of all points back up to "COMPANY"

So, I can GET the data. I think the best way to accomplish what I want is to somehow add a class to each of these elements and then style on that "active" class.

Thank you!